# MS Access Calculated Field to test if Table exist

Tags: ms-access, calculated-field

I have a list of names in my database that should have a corresponding Table named after it. I would like to have a check in the adjacent column that checks if the Table actually exists.

I could technically achieve this through code but was just wondering if a calculated field can achieve the same results.

```
ID  TableName   Exist   
1   Cat         TRUE    
2   Dog         TRUE    
3   MooMoo      FALSE   <---Table does not exist in db
```

Comment: Bad idea, referring to [Microsoft Access tips: Calculated Fields](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

You'll need a *user defined function*, UDF, to check for the table, while only native functions can be used in the expression for a calculated field.

Comment: ^This. Your column `Exist` should be in a query, where you call that UDF. @adam